# How to make sure method will receive only specific values?

Tags: c#

Maybe this is a trivial problem but I don't really know what is the best way to solve this.

I have a table in my database which columns describe a sensor.

Now there is a column that desribes different types of sensors:
- Heat sensor 
- Pressure sensor 
and so on...
It's good to use strings here because numbers don't really tell you anything.

Now to retrieve the data from database I use a repository.

```
public IEnumerable<Sensor> Select(string typeOfSensor)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Query<Sensor>()
            .Where(c =>c.TypeOfSensor == typeOfSensor);

    }
}
```

How to make sure that the user will insert the correct name of the sensor ?

I want to avoid using magic strings in my code.

First I thought about using enum but it can't store strings. Than about static classes with static constants but these don't really make the developer to use them since the type will be the same (string) and nothing stops you from not using pre defined types.

How can we do something like this (if enum could store string) ?

```
enum TypeOfSensor  //i know this is not possible but it's for example purposes
{
    HeatSensor= "Heat sensor",
    PressureSensor = "Pressure sensor"
}
```

1. We make sure developer can only insert pre defined strings

> var list = _repositorySensors.Select(TypeOfSensor.HeatSensor);

2. Than in the repository we can get the actual string

> ```
> public IEnumerable<Sensor> Select(TypeOfSensor typeOfSensor)
> {
>   using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
>   {
>       return session.Query<Sensor>()
>           .Where(c =>c.TypeOfSensor == typeOfSensor.Value);
>
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Instead of having the Type in Plaintext, you could also have another Table with ID and the Text. And then you would have a foreign key in your main table.

Comment: most databases have integer enum fields that are descriptive and yet efficient to store, search and index.

Comment: You can simply creat Enums (you dont need to assign a string), and use the Enum.GetName method to get the actual enum name as string. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Thangadurai, i assume that enum names don't match the column values, as in his example they also differ.

Comment: @Dom84, Sorry missed that part. A Check constraint on the database table will also restrict the possible values (but some may not prefer it)

Comment: @fabigler this is a standard approach but I have a database table I can't alter. So the strings there have to stay :) and yes these are strings in the database not defined by me so they have to stay the way they are with whitespaces and everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some time have passed but this is what I was looking for:

http://blog.falafel.com/introducing-type-safe-enum-pattern/

best answer I found so far. Type-safe Enum pattern. Only I didn't know that it was called like this.

I post this for anyone looking for the answer in the future.

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to be a string you could use DescriptionAttribute at your enum, to define a custom string per enum Value.

That description value could then be obtained via reflection, for example as an extension method.

```
enum TypeOfSensor 
{
    [Description("Heat sensor")]
    HeatSensor,
    [Description("Pressure sensor")]
    PressureSensor
}

private static string ToDescription(this Enum value)
{
    var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    var attributes =
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
        false);

    return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
}



public IEnumerable<Sensor> Select(TypeOfSensor typeOfSensor)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
      var sensorType = typeOfSensor.ToDescription();
      return session.Query<Sensor>()
          .Where(c =>c.TypeOfSensor == sensorType );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple case where you'll just be mapping an exact `string` to your existing `enum`, you could easily do something like this:

```
readonly Dictionary<string, TypeOfSensor> SensorTypes =
    new Dictionary<string, TypeOfSensor>
        {
            {"Heat sensor", TypeOfSensor.HeatSensor},
            {"Pressure sensor", TypeOfSensor.PressureSensor}
        };
```

Now you can validate your input easily with `SensorTypes.ContainsKey("Heat sensor")` and you can handle problematic database values appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the below instead of enum:

```
abstract class TypeOfSensor
{
    public static readonly TypeOfSensor HeatSensor = 
        new HeatTypeOfSensor();

    public static readonly TypeOfSensor PressureSensor =
        new PressureTypeOfSensor();

    private TypeOfSensor() { }

    protected abstract string Name { get; }

    public static implicit operator string(TypeOfSensor s)
    {
        return s.Name;
    }

    private class HeatTypeOfSensor : TypeOfSensor
    {
        protected override string Name
        {
            get { return "Heat Sensor"; }
        }
    }

    private class PressureTypeOfSensor : TypeOfSensor
    {
        protected override string Name
        {
            get { return "Pressure Sensor"; }
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public IEnumerable<Sensor> Select(TypeOfSensor typeOfSensor)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Query<Sensor>()
            .Where(c => c.TypeOfSensor == typeOfSensor);

    }
}
```